# Retrieve the attribute of an HTML element saved in a variable using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have all the elements saved in a variable using `jQuery` like

```
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>

var box = $('div');
```

Now I am trying to `alert/console.log` the `attribute['id']` of the div in particular index position with `jQuery` with this code -

```
console.log(box[1].attr['id']);
```

But that does not seem to work.

How can I get the attribute of an element in an array, at a particular index position to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that is not the right syntax.

```
$('div').eq(1).attr('id')
```

is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**eq(n)**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) function instead of array `[]` or you could use `box[0].id;`

```js
var box = $('div');

//OPTION 1
alert(box.eq(1).attr('id'));

//OPTION 2
alert(box[1].id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go out of jquery context and use vanilla JS: (some says it is more efficient, little faster?)

```
console.log($(box)[1].id);
```

or:

```
console.log(box[1].id);
```

Or - 'pure' jquery way:

```
console.log($(box[1]).attr('id'));
```

or:

```
console.log(box.eq(1).attr('id'));
```

or:

```
console.log(box.next().attr('id')); //even this works!
```

and probably few more ways... Ah, freedom of choice™....

Comment: Is there something missing before "Or"?

Comment: You mean: var box = $('div'); ? Except it, nothing, afaik... :)

Comment: I mean that "or" is usually used to combine alternative, e.g. "You can do this OR that".

Comment: Ah, so... i have seen that other answers are posted in the same time (or little before) i posted my answer, so.... alternatives = other answers... :)

Comment: I thought that was what you meant. But that only makes sense if the answers are in a particular order. What happens if you get lots of upvotes, so your answer rises to the top? Then THEY become the alternatives, not yours.

Comment: @Barmar, i doubt.... all meaningful options are covered in top answer already... and i am (sometimes) lazy to make edits... ;) But... since you have asked....:)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var box = $('div');
$("div#result1").html(box[1].getAttribute("id"));
$("div#result2").html($(box[1]).attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one"></div>
<div id="two"></div>
<div id="three"></div>
<div id="result1"></div>
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Please try this:

```
console.log($(box[1]).attr('id'));
```

or

```
console.log(box[1].getAttribute('id'));
```

box is a jQuery object but box[1] is a HTML element, it has getAttribute() method but doesn't have .attr() method. $(box[1]) turns it back to jQuery object.